# What is the rules of type deduction while passing pointer to template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction, type-deduction

I'm learning how to use template in C++11 and I just read an article about template, it showed me the rules of type deduction with reference. For example,

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T& param);

int x = 27;
const int cx = x;
const int& rx = x;

f(x);  // T is int, param's type is const int&
f(cx); // T is int, param's type is const int&
f(rx); // T is int, param's type is const int&
f(27); // T is int, param's type is const int&
```

Besides, it also talked about the reference collapsing:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& param);

int x = 27;
const int cx = x;
const int& rx = x;

f(x);   // x is lvalue,  so T is int&,       param's type is int&
f(cx);  // cx is lvalue, so T is const int&, param's type is const int&
f(rx);  // rx is lvalue, so T is const int&, param's type is const int&
f(27);  // 27 is rvalue, so T is int,        param's type is int&&
```

Well, for now I understood all of these but now, I'm thinking about pointer. This issue totally explode my brain but it seems that it would become extremely complex.

For example, let's say we have `int *`, `const int *`. Now if we have threse template functions below:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T param);

template<typename T>
void f(T *param);

template<typename T>
void f(const T *param);

template<typename T>
void f(T& param);

template<typename T>
void f(const T& param);

template<typename T>
void f(T&& param);
```

If we pass a `int *`, how does the compile do the type deduction? What about a `const int *`?

Comment: Why do you think pointers are any different? A pointer has a type.  `int` is a type. `int*` is another type.  The deduction occurs on types. So `T` will be a pointer type, if a pointer is passed in to the `param`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, type deduction in templates falls in three different categories, wherein parameter type of the template function is either a 1) reference or pointer, 2) a forwarding (a.k.a universal) reference, or finally 3) neither pointer/reference or forwarding reference.

So, if you have a pointer, type deduction is working like this is these three cases.

**For case 1-A:**

```
template<typename T>
void f(T* param);

int x = 27;
int* px = &x;
const int* cpx = &x;

f(px);   // T is int and param's type is int *
f(cpx);  // T is const int and param's type is const int *
```

**For case 1-B:**

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& param);

int x = 27;
int* px = &x;
const int* cpx = &x;

f(px);   // T is int* and param's type is int*&
f(cpx);  // T is const int* and param's type is const int*&
```

**For case 2:**

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& param);

int x = 27;
int* px = &x;
const int* cpx = &x;

f(px);   // T is int*& and param's type is int*&
f(cpx);  // T is const int*& and param's type is const int*&
```

**For case 3:**

```
template<typename T>
void f(T param);

int x = 27;
int* px = &x;
const int* cpx = &x;

f(px);   // T is int * and param's type is int *
f(cpx);  // T is const int * and param's type is const int *
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. It helps. So would you add the case 4: `template<typename T> void f(T &param);`? At least, it may be helpful too for me.

Comment: @Yves The case you mentioned is not case 4, but it is a part of case 1, because type deduction rules are pretty the same. So, I divided case 1 into case 1-A and case 1-B for more clarifications.